# Filtering with magento2

Tags: magento2, database

I have problem with magento2 FilterGroupBuilder. I need to set filter where active_until date is between today and March 3 OR active_until before January 5. My code looks like:

```
public function dot4()
{
    $filter[] = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setConditionType('gteq')
        ->setField('active_until')
        ->setValue(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
        ->create();
    $filter[] = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setConditionType('lteq')
        ->setField('active_until')
        ->setValue(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('March 3')))
        ->create();
    $filter[] = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setConditionType('lt')
        ->setField('active_until')
        ->setValue(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('January 5')))
        ->create();

    $filter_group = [
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[0])
            ->create(),
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[1])
            ->create(),
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[2])
            ->create(),
    ];

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups($filter_group);

    $list = $this->vendorInterface->getList(
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
    )->getItems();

    return $list;
}
```

And MySQL query shows:

```
'SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `Training5_VendorRepository` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`active_until` >= '2016-01-29 12:06:25')) AND ((`active_until` <= '2016-03-03 00:00:00')) AND ((`active_until` < '2016-01-05 00:00:00'))' (length=216)
```

If i change $filter_group to that structure:

```
    $filter_group = [
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[0])
            ->addFilter($filter[1])
            ->create(),
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[2])
            ->create(),
    ];
```

Query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `Training5_VendorRepository` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`active_until` >= '2016-01-29 12:13:38') OR (`active_until` <= '2016-03-03 00:00:00')) AND ((`active_until` < '2016-01-05 00:00:00'))
```

But still it's not a solution...
So how to group filters to show query like this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `Training5_VendorRepository` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`active_until` >= '2016-01-29 12:13:38') AND (`active_until` <= '2016-03-03 00:00:00')) OR ((`active_until` < '2016-01-05 00:00:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$filter_group = [
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filter[0])
            ->create(),
        $this->filterGroupBuilder
             ->addFilter($filter[1])
            ->addFilter($filter[2])
            ->create(),
    ];
```

Comment: It shows: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `Training5_VendorRepository` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`active_until` >= '2016-01-29 13:31:12')) AND ((`active_until` <= '2016-03-03 00:00:00') OR (`active_until` < '2016-01-05 00:00:00')) but still don't show (`active_until` < '2016-01-05 00:00:00') rows.

Comment: I believe your query is [p v (q ^ r)]. Its equal to [(p v q) ^ (p v r)] and this one you can create with searchCriteriaBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt work anymore on 2.1.3
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8300

Please reference that ticket